# How to set onfocus on datepicker vue material?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-material

I'm trying to write a function to be executed when the datepicker get focus, but I don't know how.

Here is my page code:

```
<div class="md-layout-item md-small-size-100 md-size-22">
    <md-datepicker v-model="birthDate" :md-open-on-focus="false" ref="birthDateEl">
        <label>Birth date</label>
    </md-datepicker>
</div>
```

I got a working code, but I think that this is not the better solution:

```
mounted(){

    this.$refs.birthDateEl.$refs.input.$el.onfocus = function() {
        this.onBirthDateFocus("some param");
      };
},
```

A good solution should be put "onfocus" in the template code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to listen to `focusin` event on `<md-datepicker>`, because it bubbles up the element tree (unlike `focus` event). You should also use `.native` modifier, which is required when listening to native events on a custom component.

In the event handler function, you should probably check that the event was fired on the exact input which represents the datepicker.

Template:

```
<md-datepicker @focusin.native="onBirthDateFocus($event)" ...>
```

Script:

```
methods: {
  onBirthDateFocus(event) {
    if (event.target.id === 'datePickerInput') {
      /*...*/
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your solution works with "md-input" component, but not with "md-datepicker". It looks like a bug in vue material datepicker.

Comment: @Beetlejuice It may not be a bug, event bubbling may just be stopped (`event.stopPropagation()`) somewhere inside the `md-picker` component. You can try to use `click` event instead. Or stay with `focusin` event and use capturing `@focusin.capture="onBirthDateFocus(...)"`. This way event handler will be called on the parent component first and child component will not block it.

Comment: I put @focusin="onBirthDateFocus($event)" in the "div" element and now it bubbles... I think this is enougth, but strange.

Comment: @Beetlejuice Now I see the problem was caused by lacking `.native` modifier, which is required for custom components (https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components). You probably don't have to use `.capture` anymore. I updated my answer.